# Newest jQuery API has catch block?

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I believe the latest version of the jQuery API is 2.2, but it seems to not follow the latest ES6 Promise spec.

To my knowledge, we can do

```
$.ajax().then(function onResolved(){

}, function onRejected(){

});
```

but it appears that adding a catch block is not allowed

```
$.ajax().then(function onResolved(){

}, function onRejected(){

}).catch(function(err){   //will throw error

});
```

is that right or did I mess something up?

Comment: [jQuery 3.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/) will support `catch` and Promises/A+ compatible `then`. It probably will never follow the ES6 spec though.

Comment: huh, thanks, do you recommend the fetch API then?

Comment: Sure, go for it. It's a much better fit if you want to use ES6 promises anyway.